# How to properly clear history in ionic?

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework

So I am testing my app via browser (chrome), and I have problems clearing old views/cache. So this is the part where I sign out of my app:

[image]

As you can see, when I click Log out, this is the code firing:

```
   Auth.$signOut().then(function(){
        $ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({
                disableBack: true,
                historyRoot: true
        });
        $ionicHistory.clearHistory();
        $ionicHistory.clearCache();
        $state.go('login');
   });
```

This works though when I try to login again in my login page, this is what fires:

```
$ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({
  disableBack: true
});
$ionicHistory.clearHistory();
$ionicHistory.clearCache();
$state.go("menu.myReports");
```

It also works but I still see this same view before I logged out:

[image]

Instead of just:

[image]

I want to clear every history, cache or whatever whenever I sign out. Is that even possible? I'm using `AngularFire` for my database.

Comment: are you using the auth from firebase?

Comment: @m1crdy Yes, the email and password auth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well this is an old issue, but for anyone that's coming 2017 or later I will explain what really happens and how to solve it:

The code of $ionicHistory.clearCache():

```
clearCache: function(stateIds) {
return $timeout(function() {
$ionicNavViewDelegate._instances.forEach(function(instance) {
instance.clearCache(stateIds);
});
});
},
```

So, as you can see, it takes 1 parameter cllaed stateIds which is an array of stateId. Indeed i struggled to find out that stateId is nothing more than stateName.

So, let's go deeper. The code of $ionicNavView.clearCache which is used in the line above "instance.clearCache(stateIds)" is:

```
self.clearCache = function(stateIds) {
var viewElements = $element.children();
var viewElement, viewScope, x, l, y, eleIdentifier;
for (x = 0, l = viewElements.length; x < l; x++) {
viewElement = viewElements.eq(x);

  if (stateIds) {
    eleIdentifier = viewElement.data(DATA_ELE_IDENTIFIER);

    for (y = 0; y < stateIds.length; y++) {
      if (eleIdentifier === stateIds[y]) {
        $ionicViewSwitcher.destroyViewEle(viewElement);
      }
    }
    continue;
  }

  if (navViewAttr(viewElement) == VIEW_STATUS_CACHED) {
    $ionicViewSwitcher.destroyViewEle(viewElement);

  } else if (navViewAttr(viewElement) == VIEW_STATUS_ACTIVE) {
    viewScope = viewElement.scope();
    viewScope && viewScope.$broadcast('$ionicView.clearCache');
  }

}
};
```

`

And as you can see in the code, this clearCache DOES NOT CLEAR ALL CACHES, instead, it destroy all cached views that matches a value in the stateIds array. If there's no parameter IT JUST DESTROY THE ACTUAL VIEW.

So the solution for this, using just the Ionic way is to call $ionicHistory.clearCache() with all your state names in an array as parameter.

E.g:

$ionicHistory.clearCache(['login', 'map', 'home']);
I cannot belive any Ionic developer didnt dug into the code before, or missed this simple datail.
I Hope someone takes advantage of this, even being so late.